# npm install gulp-cli failure - 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: npm

When I run this command:

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

I get this output:

```
npm ERR! code E503
npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable: gulp-cli@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-08T19_33_47_294Z-debug.log
```

This is what's on the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '-g', 'gulp-cli' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.16.1
4 verbose npm-session ea6642bf85c436af
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-cli 70153ms attempt #3
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for gulp-cli@latest 503 Service Unavailable: gulp-cli@latest
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 70496ms
11 verbose stack Error: 503 Service Unavailable: gulp-cli@latest
11 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
11 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
12 verbose cwd /home/usuario/php/router
13 verbose Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
14 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp-cli"
15 verbose node v8.16.1
16 verbose npm  v6.4.1
17 error code E503
18 error 503 Service Unavailable: gulp-cli@latest
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How do I fix it?

**npm version: 6.4.1**

**node version: v8.16.1**

Upgrading either node or npm is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the company proxy, which couldn't resolve the address of registry.npmjs.com. The network manager configured it to pass through the proxy, but that also didn't help because npm ignored my `NO_PROXY` system config.

The only thing that did work was configuring npm to use another registry.